# Passing JavaScript Array To PHP and manipulate them

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

ARRAYTEST.HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="go to php" onclick="show()">
<br><br>

<script type="text/javascript">
var a = new Array(3,4,5);
function show(){
    $.ajax({        
        type: "POST",
        url: "arra.php",
        data: {test : a},
        success: function() {
        alert("success");        
        }
    });
}
</script>
</body>
```

```
ARRA.PHP

<?php 
    $arr = $_REQUEST['test'];

    echo $arr[0];
    echo $arr[1];
    echo $arr[2];
?>
```

am new to php. 
here is my code.am trying to post array values to php in javascript using ajax. am not getting where i am wrong.
thanx in advance :)

Comment: What failure are you exactly facing?

Comment: echo values are not  dispaying in my php page.

Comment: Is the file named `arra.php` or `ARRA.PHP` on the server? Can you access it with curl?

Comment: it's arra,php no i didn't try curl

Comment: @kishore see the `console` output/response for your request!

Comment: the values getting posted in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include Jquery script in your code:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Also move the `<script>` tag inside `<html>` tag:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <input type="button" id="btn" value="go to php" onclick="show()">
    <br><br>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var a = new Array(3,4,5);
    function show(){
        $.ajax({        
            type: "POST",
            url: "arra.php",
            data: {test : a},
            success: function() {
            alert("success");        
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thankyu. am getting the alert message "success". but in my php page the echo values are not displaying.

Comment: @user3476020 that is because when you open/refresh your php file the html is served to you once again. If you check the `concole` the response will show you that the `$_POST` values are echoed. Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Comment: how can  i manipulate those array values in php ?

Comment: @kishore rather broad question, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: sorry. am new to php. trying to learn it. how to check concole ?

Comment: @kishore hit `F12` to open developer tools in your browser and then check Net/Network tab (depends what dev tools you are using)

Comment: values are getting posted. then y aren't the they dispaying ?

Comment: @kishore they are displayed, see the console. There you can see the requests you have made and the response. In response text the values will be clearly visible!

Comment: yes man (Y) it worked. last clarification.in success function in ajax. except alert what should i give. jus to move to php page

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript method so you send json data to the server:

```
$.ajax({        
    type: "POST",
    url: "arra.php",
    data: {test : JSON.stringify(a)},
    success: function(data) {
        alert("success " + data); // now you will see the echo-ed array elements on the alert message
    }
});
```

Than on your php file you can read it like this:

```
$arr = json_decode($_POST['test'], true);

echo $arr[0];
echo $arr[1];
echo $arr[2];
```

Comment: oops ! that is not working

Comment: I added the functionality how to receive the data on your javascript. Now you will see the data on the alert message.

Comment: success message is working. but am not gettng the echo values in php.

Comment: how are you testing the echo values in php?

Comment: success: function(data) {
            alert(data);        
            }   // in html file

Comment: that wil echo directly in php page by echo command  ryt ?

Comment: you should remove the dataType: 'json' as you are not expecting json data from the server.

Comment: nope. that is also not working. i have to manipulate those array values in php. am trying to fix it. but not working

Comment: can you check with developer tools(on network tab) what is the response of the request?

Comment: method is getting posted in php. but y aren't they displaying the values ?

Comment: try to var_dump the whole array and add some custom data so you know that at least you are receiving it?

Comment: yes ! am recieving it (Y) . but how do i disay my values ?

Comment: is it solved or you still don't get the values from the array?

Comment: am getting the values in alert message since i given in js page as alert(data). what should i do if i i have to move to php page without alert messages ?

Comment: what do you mean to move to php page? You can use the data variable in javascript to change the DOM or show alerts..

Comment: cool. am clear now. thanks fr u time man. helped me a lot :)

Comment: You are welcome. I hope that solved your problem :).

Answer (score 0):

you missing jQuery library in your example link it like:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

and redefine  `onclick="show()"`

Comment: thankyu. am getting the alert message ("success"). but in my php page the echo values are not displaying

Comment: For data retrieve from your script you must changes succes method:

        `success: function(data) {
            alert(data);        
        }`

Comment: @kishore see my comment below.

Comment: nope. tried that. that's not displaying any values

Comment: try add full path to your url param in ajax call: